# Weighted probability with long doubles

Tags: c++, vector, probability, long-double

I am working with an array of roughly 2000 elements in C++.

Each element represents the probability of that element being selected randomly.

I then have convert this array into a cumulative array, with the intention of using this to work out which element to choose when a dice is rolled.

Example array:
{1,2,3,4,5}

Example cumulative array:
{1,3,6,10,15}

I want to be able to select 3 in the cumulative array when numbers 3, 4 or 5 are rolled.

The added complexity is that my array is made up of long doubles. Here's an example of a few consecutive elements:

0.96930161525189592646367317541056252139242133125662803649902343750
0.96941377254127855667142910078837303444743156433105468750000000000
0.96944321382974149711383993199831365927821025252342224121093750000
0.96946143938926617454089618153290075497352518141269683837890625000
0.96950069444055009509463721739663810694764833897352218627929687500
0.96951751803395748961766908990966840065084397792816162109375000000

This could be a terrible way of doing weighted probabilities with this data set, so I'm open to any suggestions of better ways of working this out.

Comment: Why do you need sooo long number?

Comment: I'm pretty bad at explaining, so here's a simplified example

{Item1 - 100, Item2 - 200}

I need to know that Item1 occurs 100/300 times. It just so happens that with my 2000 items, the values make probabilities like above. I'd like to keep as precise as possible because reducing the probabilities could affect my final values negatively (i.e. Item1 never appearing).

Comment: See [`partial_sum`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sum).

Comment: And `std::upper_bound`… subtract 1 from the result to get the element "at least equal to" the argument.

Comment: boost has an RNG for EXACTLY this purpose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`partial_sum`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sum):

```
unsigned int SIZE = 5;
int array[SIZE] = {1,2,3,4,5};
int partials[SIZE] = {0};

partial_sum(array, array+SIZE, partials);
// partials is now {1,3,6,10,15}
```

The value you want from the array is available from the partial sums:

```
12 == array[2] + array[3] + array[4];

12 == partials[4] - partials[1];
```

The total is obviously the last value in the partial sums:

```
15 == partial[4];
```

Answer (score 1):

consider storing the information as an integer numerator and denominator so that there is no loss of precision until the final step.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually do this using stream selection without having to compute an array of partial sums. Here's code I have for this in Java:

```
public static int selectRandomWeighted(double[] wts, Random rnd) {
    int selected = 0;
    double total = wts[0];

    for( int i = 1; i < wts.length; i++ ) {
        total += wts[i];

        if( rnd.nextDouble() <= (wts[i] / total)) {
            selected = i;
        }
    }

    return selected;        
}
```

The above could potentially be further improved using [Kahan summation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation) if you want to preserve as many digits of accuracy in the sum as possible.

However, if you want to draw from this array repeatedly, then pre-computing an array of partial sums and using binary search to find the right index will be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I've solved this one.

I just did a binary split search, but instead of just having

```
if (arr[middle] == value)
```

I added in an OR

```
if (arr[middle] == value || (arr[middle] < value && arr[middle+1] > value))
```

This seems to handle it in the way I was hoping for.

Comment: What if there is only `1` value in the array?

Comment: There will be an absolute minimum of 1000 items in the array.